# Inconsistences when comparing linear regression models with advanced features in Python

Tags: regression, data-visualization, predictive-models, python, scatterplot

Good morning ! I am learning how to do linear regression models with python and I encountered difficulties when widening a model to some advanced featues

I have a set of data for housing sales depicted in the following graph :

[image]

And actually with several features :

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
id   & price & bedrooms  &bathrooms&  sqft_living&  sqft_lot&  floors&  waterfront\\
\hline
7129300520   & 221900  & 3 &  1 & 1180 & 5650 & 1 & 0\\
6414100192  &  538000  &3&  2.25 & 2570  &7242&  2&  0\\
5631500400  &  180000 & 2 & 1 & 770 & 10000 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
\end{array}

And a few more like

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
view  &condition  &grade & sqft_above & sqft_basement & yr_built & yr_renovated  &zipcode&  lat\\
\hline
\end{array}

## The original attempt

I did a linear regression, (I don't perfectly understand how does this work, especially the itereations and passes, but here is what I coded) :

```
sqft_model = graphlab.linear_regression.create(train_data, target='price', features=['sqft_living'],validation_set=None)
```

I was then able to predict the future prices :

```
plt.plot(test_data['sqft_living'],test_data['price'],'.',
        test_data['sqft_living'],sqft_model.predict(test_data),'-')
```

[image]

## An advanced attempt

Now, going back to the original dataset, I built a model using the following features

```
advanced_features = [
'bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'floors', 'zipcode',
'condition', # condition of house               
'grade', # measure of quality of construction               
'waterfront', # waterfront property             
'view', # type of view              
'sqft_above', # square feet above ground                
'sqft_basement', # square feet in basement              
'yr_built', # the year built                
'yr_renovated', # the year renovated                
'lat', 'long', # the lat-long of the parcel             
'sqft_living15', # average sq.ft. of 15 nearest neighbors               
'sqft_lot15', # average lot size of 15 nearest neighbors 
]
```

I then did :

```
sqft_model_homemade = graphlab.linear_regression.create(test_data, target='price', features=advanced_features,validation_set=None)
```

But when trying to plot it here is what it returned :

```
plt.plot(test_data['sqft_living'],test_data['price'],'.',
        test_data['sqft_living'],sqft_model_homemade.predict(test_data),'-')
```

[image]

This seems so incoherent. Can you help me understand if I coded a mistake in the second linear regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are visualizing a hyper-plane consisting of 18 Dimensions projected in a 2-Dimensional space, which is simply not correct.

If you want to visualice the model in a plane (2D) you should first compute a Principal Component Analysis, then rotate the dataset and keep only the first dimension (which will be the principal dimension, the one with higher variance)
And then you will be able to plot the graph you are interested in.